# Connecting SharePoint to Database as a service like AWS RDS or Azure SQL Databases

Tags: sharepoint, azure, amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds

Having a SharePoint on an instance [EC2 - AWS / Azure VM - Azure ] is the way we take SharePoint on Cloud (leaving the SharePoint Online with Office365). It would really great if we can connect the SharePoint instance with the Database as a Service like AWS RDS or Azure SQL Databases.

Is it possible in the first place? This is for both the cloud vendors AWS and Azure. I guess the main hurdle would be to bring the Database end point under the Subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint does not support using a Database as a service as its store.  That said there are other integration points between SPS2k13 & Azure (e.g. Azure Web Sites, Auth Service, etc.).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179922.aspx